# Maven: Three Jars in one project. Trying to use an assembly, but not getting pom.xml and pom.properties embedded in the jars

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project that produces three different jar files:

- Server.jar: This contains all classes and resources. A standard jar
- Client.jar: This contains only a few *external* classes and no resources.
- ServerSDK.jar: This contains all the classes, resources, test classes, and other configuration files.

I've decided to do all three jars in a single project, so a change in any of the sources spawns a Jenkins build and deploys all three at once. I build the Server.jar as my standard `pom.xml` jar. Then, I use assemblies to build the Client.jar and the ServerSDK.jar.

I have the assemblies that build the other two jars, and everything is 99% of the way I like it, but there is bit of munging I'd like to do.

1. We add a few entries in our `MANIFEST.MF` file to incorporate the Jenkins build information and project information.
2. In a standard Maven jar, the `pom.xml` and `pom.properties` are embedded in the `META-INF` directory.

The first one I have managed to do via the `<assembly>` configuration in my `maven-assembly-plugin`. The second one I can't seem to get to work even though I have `<addMavenDescriptor>` set to `true` in my `<assembly>` configuration.

Here's my `maven-assembly-plugin` section in my `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <addMavenDescriptor>true</addMavenDescriptor>
            <manifestSections>
                <manifestSection>
                    <name>Build-Information</name>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Project-Name>${env.JOB_NAME}</Project-Name>
                        <Build-Number>${env.BUILD_NUMBER}</Build-Number>
                        <SVN-Revision>${env.SVN_REVISION}</SVN-Revision>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </manifestSection>
                <manifestSection>
                    <name>Module-Information</name>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Group-ID>${project.groupId}</Group-ID>
                        <Artifact-ID>${project.artifactId}</Artifact-ID>
                        <Version>${project.version}</Version>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </manifestSection>
            </manifestSections>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>Client</id>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>Client</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/client.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The `<manifestSections>` work just fine, but the `<addMavenDescriptor>` doesn't seem to be working although I've explicitly set it to `true`.

According to the documentation on the [maven-archiver-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html):

> Whether the created archive will contain these two Maven files:
>
> - The pom file, located in the archive in `META-INF/maven/${groupId}/${artifactId}/pom.xml`
> - A `pom.properties` file, located in the archive in `META-INF/maven/${groupId}/${artifactId}/pom.properties`
>
> The default value is `true`.

According the `maven-assembly-plugin` page:

> `<archive>`
>   This is a set of instructions to the archive builder, especially for building .jar files. It enables you to specify a Manifest file for the jar, in addition to other options. See Maven Archiver Reference

Is there something simple I'm missing here?

Comment: Hmm your configuration looks correct at first glance. I'll try to repro something. Note that instead of having a single project building 3 JARs, it'd be preferable to split this into 3 modules of a multi-module Maven project. This way, you still keep your requirement of building and deploying the whole thing in Jenkins when a change occurs in any of the module, and it's the recommended Maven approach here. You can then add a 4th module making the final assembly.

Comment: I always thought of modules as compiling their own classfiles - like an ear or a war. Here, all three jars share the same classfiles. Two of them use all of them, and one uses a subset. I'll have to read up on modules again and see how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maven Assembly Plugin actually ignores the `addMavenDescriptor` parameter, and will never include the Maven descriptor in the resulting assembly. This can be seen [in the source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-assembly-plugin-2.6/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/assembly/archive/ManifestCreationFinalizer.java?view=markup#l133): only the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file is possibly added to the JAR archive.

I couldn't find an existing JIRA issue about this, so I went ahead and created [MASSEMBLY-835](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-835) to track this.

---

A work-around for now would be to add the files yourself in the assembly descriptor:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
  <id>client</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <files>
    <file>
      <source>pom.xml</source>
      <outputDirectory>META-INF/maven/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}</outputDirectory>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>${project.build.directory}/maven-archiver/pom.properties</source>
      <outputDirectory>META-INF/maven/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}</outputDirectory>
    </file>
  </files>
  <!-- rest of your configuration -->
</assembly>
```

This adds a `<files>` configuration that adds the `pom.xml` and the generated `pom.properties` into the target directory.

Note that the `pom.properties` is generated by the [Maven Archiver](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/) component during the default package goal [into the `target/maven-archiver` directory](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/shared/tags/maven-archiver-3.1.1/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/archiver/MavenArchiver.java?view=markup#l593); therefore, in order for it to be present when making your assembly, the Assembly Plugin has to be bound to the phase `package` (or later in the lifecycle), and the current Maven project needs to be of packaging JAR / WAR / EAR / EJB / RAR... but not POM which doesn't package an archive. The primary artifact of the Maven project also needs to be built (if you skip the generation of the primary JAR of a JAR project, the `pom.properties` won't be generated).

This works in a large majority of cases. But if you want a bullet-proof solution, you can just create the file yourself. Create a `pom.properties` somewhere in your project (example, base directory) with the following content:

```
#Generated by Apache Maven ${maven.version}
version=${project.version}
groupId=${project.groupId}
artifactId=${project.artifactId}
```

and in the previous assembly descriptor, have instead:

```
<file>
  <source>pom.properties</source>
  <outputDirectory>META-INF/maven/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}</outputDirectory>
  <filtered>true</filtered>
</file>
```

This would correctly replace the placeholders inside the `pom.properties` that was created, and mimic what Maven Archiver would do.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that might be the case, but not really being a Java developer, I wouldn't be 100% sure of my reading of the code. I figured asking on StackOverflow would either confirm it's a bug, or (more likely) I don't know what I'm doing. I'm still playing around with this. I realize that to specify these other two jars, you now need a `<classifer>` (which also explains why if I don't have `<appendAssemblyId>` set, Maven throws a fit. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidW. In this case, it's a bug :). I will take a look at fixing it and this will probably be included in the next 3.0.0 release of the plugin.